# Can I prefer LBA to CHS addressing in Operating System Development?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-16, bootloader

I am developing a minimalistic Operating System. I created a MBR that looks in the `Master Partition Table` for active partition. The Problem I am facing is with the **loading of sectors into memory**.

With respect to loading sectors, I came across two schemes,

- CHS addressing
- LBA addressing

I read that CHS is supported by almost all BIOS but the problem lies in the fact that it can address atmost `8GB` and this drawback is rectified with LBA.

With those being said, I would like to ask some questions:

**Question 1:**

What scheme is best to choose with? If CHS, Is there any way I could access above the 8GB mark?

**Question 2:**

In LBA, how will I be able to load a sector from (say)partition 4?

**ie:** How will I be able to find the starting block number of 4th partition?

---

**Note:** The scenario happens in `16 bit real mode`.

---

Thanks.

OS : Ubuntu

Compiler : CC

Comment: But this question is different at least with the sub questions I asked. Kindly answer the question.

Comment: 1. In short, forget CHS. 2. To load from partition 4 you should read about partition tables and understand how it works. Then you won't ask this question. Again, in short, you get starting LBA of partition 4 from MBR to be able to convert relative sector in partition to absolute LBA, then read

Comment: So, Can I rely on LBA completely rather than CHS? @Alexander Zhak

Comment: Asking two questions per post is not following the SO etiquette. You can't really argue that "one of your sub-question is not a duplicate" - there is no such thing as a sub-question. Even admitting their existence (which sometimes we do) in your case the first is an exact duplicate that **you** already asked. The second is too broad/not researched - which partition scheme? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Not because of the similarity to the duplicate, but because they are both authored by the same nick and are close to identical.

Comment: BTW: CHS is ancient. Today, there's no alternative to LBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the BIOS extended read function, which uses a 64 bit LBA (a Sata drive would use the lower 48 bits of the LBA).

```
INT 13 - IBM/MS INT 13 Extensions - EXTENDED READ
       AH = 42h
       DL = drive number
       DS:SI -> disk address packet
Return: CF clear if successful
           AH = 00h
       CF set on error
           AH = error code
           disk address packet's block count field set to number of blocks
             successfully transferred

Format of disk address packet:
Offset Size     Description
 00h   BYTE     10h (size of packet)
 01h   BYTE     reserved (0)
 02h   WORD     number of blocks to transfer
 04h   DWORD    -> transfer buffer
 08h   QWORD    starting absolute block number  (LBA)
```

The question mentions MBR. Normally the first sector on a hard drive is a partition sector that includes a table of partitions (typically 4 of them), and which one is active. The partition boot code usually relocates itself (Microsoft relocates to 00000h:00600h), and reads in the MBR from the active partition into 00000h:07c00h, and then jumps to the MBR code.

Comment: The Starting Absolute Block address is `QWORD` which is 64 bit long. Where will I get this value from? The MBR partition table has a relative sector field which is same as starting sector of a partition but is 32 bits long. So, should I pad the remaining bits with `0`? Also should I consider `endianess` when moving the data from Partition table to Disk address packet? @rcgldr

Comment: Store the 32 bit relative sector into the first (lower) dword of the qword block number and a zero in the second (upper) dword of the qword block number. This assumes you're using a normal 32 bit store which would be little endian.